# How to discuss a pull request in github

Tags: git, github

I have a little problem when my colleages or me when we are not agree with a piece of code or way to do the things in a pull request. I was wondering how are you solving the discussion in the case of the reviewer are dissagree with the coder.

1) The PR will be not approved and wont merged

or

2) The coder don't accept the review and reject the reviews. The code will be merged anyway.

The context is the reviewer and the pull request owner are in the same plane as 
developers and are both owner of the porject.

Thanks yours opinions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume two persons with the same owner privileges, one is an author of PR, the other one is the reviewer:

1. Testing

   First the code should be tested if it actually solves the desired problem. If not, then there's no need for merging.
2. Requesting changes

   If the code fixes the problem or implements a new feature, then the design issues rise, such as indentation, tab/spaces, foolishly named variables or even a code pattern/style guide the original repository maybe tries to stay close to.
3. Code is fine

   If the code is fine on both sides (algo + design) and there's still someone who disapproves, there are pretty much these issues:

   - the code just *doesn't feel right*
   - unnecessary feature
   - internal issues - maybe the reviewer and author of PR don't like each other

If the third "phase" comes, then in this case mostly a third person (with the same level of privileges) would be needed to judge the code.

It'd be kind of utopian thinking that a third person would always solve such a situation, therefore here are some endings you should get used to:

- PR will be left open and solved in the future
- PR will be closed

  You're welcome to make a fork and work on that feature, it's in git's nature after all (see [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control)) and maybe propose the code in a new PR in the future
- PR will be merged

Comment: I appreciate very much your comment and to having a 3rd person it's a great idea. Thanks for your opinion. I hope more comments of the people experience of how to solve disscusions and thinking differences in PRs

Comment: @Keniako I'm not that positive as there are already 3 votes for closing this question while I'm writing and I'm probably the only one caring enough to actually try to answer such a broad question which is probably not even related to SO directly, rather some other part of SE e.g. [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). :)

Comment: I know it is a broad question, but it is a fact that the discussions exists in the day to day of working. I did the question because it is usual to have this problem in my team and I needed to eard how another teams solve this. To having a third person for example it's a simple idea, but which has not occurred to us. I like to have more comments and ideas. But If this topic is not interesting for others or don't have this problem, it will be fine for me. (Even someone voted negatively, I can understand that)